# RPackage library exception (error 1000)

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I have the following code in an Execute R Module.

---

```
# Input
data1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # Qualitative with 8 variables

install.packages("src/graphics.zip", lib.loc = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = 
TRUE)
install.packages("src/grDevices.zip", lib.loc = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = 
TRUE)
install.packages("src/stats.zip", lib.loc = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = 
TRUE)
install.packages("src/utils.zip", lib.loc = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = 
TRUE)
install.packages("src/MASS.zip", lib.loc = ".", repos = NULL, verbose = 
TRUE)
success <- library("MASS", lib.loc = ".", logical.return = TRUE, verbose = 
TRUE)
library(MASS)

mca <- mca(data1, nf = 10)

mca1 <- data.frame(mca$rs)

# Output
maml.mapOutputPort("mca1");
```

---

When I execute I am getting the following error:

RPackage library exception: Attempting to obtain R output before invoking execution process. (Error 1000)

But it is working fine in RStudio.

I also have a node that does the same process and it works without errors. I have executed it several times, sometimes it has worked for me and then it has returned error.

Please let me know what the issue is.

With regards,

Celia